# How to turn int[] to Integer[] in java?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a function taking an int array and need to have that array put into an arraylist

So I use `list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));`

However since `list` is `ArrayList<Integer>`, the `addAll` only accepts `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`

How should I box the primitive array into an Integer Object array?

Comment: Loop through the elements of the primitive list, establish an object, and add it to the 2nd list.

Comment: `List<Integer>.addAll` accepts neither `Integer[]` nor `int[]`.

Comment: @veer sry I meant asList method :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28int%5B%5D%29) from Apache Commons:

```
Integer[] integerArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(intArray);
```

to follow on from this, to create a `List<Integer>`, you can use:

```
List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(intArray));
```

Comment: No point in first converting `int[]` to equivalent `Integer[]`, then wrapping that via `Arrays.asList` only to copy all when doing `list.addAll`.

Comment: @MichaelBuen I'm afraid I don't quite see your point. I described what `list.addAll(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(array)));` does. What separate code? If you're stating that Apache Commons is a separate library, yes I'm very well aware of that.

Comment: @veer I mean, the integerArray is not involved on second code. They can be used independently. ArrayUtils.toObject need not accept `Integer[]`, it can accept `int[]` out-of-the-box

Comment: @MichaelBuen yes, okay, I am very well aware the snippets are distinct. My point still stands :-p Just figured I'd point out it's doing excessive work. I never stated that `ArrayUtils.toObject` accepted `Integer[]`. Maybe you should reread my comment :-)

Comment: @veer Well that's Java for us ツ I'm mostly a C# coder, I dabble with Java only recently, it surprises me that a `List<int>`(works on C#) is not a valid construct even Java already has autoboxing. Cheers! ツ

Comment: @MichaelBuen yeah Java generics are not as powerful as those in C# :-/

Answer (score 2):

```
static void addAll(final Collection<Integer> collection, final int[] v) {
  for (final int i : v) {
    collection.add(i);
  }
}
...
addAll(list, array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the int array and instantiate new `Integer` objects, and place them in the `ArrayList`.  You won't be able to use autoboxing since that only works for primitives.  Arrays aren't primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), you can just use

```
list.addAll(Ints.asList(array));
```

...which, by the way, creates fewer unnecessary objects than the Apache Commons technique will.  (Specifically, it won't bother creating an `Integer[]`; it'll just return a `List<Integer>` view of an `int[]`.)

Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.